# HTML/php header include only works when indented

Tags: php, html, header, include

I have written the header for my website in html and have included it with:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

At the beginning of all my pages.  What I'm finding however is that it will only display the header if the first line is indented.  If I don't leave empty space, the header will not show, and the following special characters will display at the top of my webpage (`ï»¿`).

What should I do?

This is my `header.php` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>       
   <body>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="Homepage.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="OurPractice.php">Practice</a></li>
         <li><a href="Services.php">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="CRT.php">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="DryEye.php">Ect</a></li>
      </ul>
```

This is my `body.php` file:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
      This is my body text ect.
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `head` section:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

This because your file encoding is currently (UTF8-BOM) try save it as (UTF-8) only. See this post also for more information: [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)